# How to add a name to the route when using controller and not a function to route to in Laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I guess, the one line question doesn't explain what I'm looking for well enough. So, here's an example of what I'm talking about: (based on the [Laravel4 Routing documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing))

The way I create a route for the controller:

```
Route::get('user/profile', "UserController@profile" );
```

The way I create a name for the route so that I can later refer to it when generating URLs:

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', function()
{
    //
}));

// Now I can use this
$url = URL::route('profile');
```

Now, obviously you wouldn't want to write your controllers as functions right in the `routes.php`, so how do I create a name like in the 2nd example, but using the controller like the example 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can name your route to controller exactly the same way. Put controller and method name as second item in array under "uses" keyword:

```
Route::get('user/profile', array("as" => "profile", "uses" => "UserController@profile"));
```

Comment: Seems like Laravel 3 had it in the documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing